# Limit of function at inf +inf while limit of derivative is negative or -inf

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Is it possible to have a function that has a limit of +inf as x approaches +inf but its derivative has a negative limit at +inf or even has -inf as its limit on +inf? Intuitively it doesn't seem so and i wasn't able to find anything contradictory.
If its false can it be proven? Also it'd be kinda nice if we could put forward a couple of rules like this one regarding the sign of limits derivatives and antiderivatives if of course they hold true and can be proven.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f'$ tends to a negative limit as $x \to \infty$ then $f$ is decreasing on $[c,\infty)$ for some $c$. But then $f(x)$ cannot tend to $\infty$. [ $f(x)  \leq f(c)$ for all $x >c$. If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$ then we must have a number $d$ such that  $f (x) >c$ for all $x>d$. But these inequalities are inconsistent for an $x$ which exceeds both $c$ and $d$].

Comment: My thought process was that precisely, can we prove the last statement?

Comment: @DuckHunterZx I have added some details.